# What is an unnamed getter and setter in JavaScript? What are they used for?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I know that in *JavaScript*, an object may contain *getters* and *setters*:

```js
const myObj = {
  get value() { return 'foo' },
  set value(val) { this. y = val }
}
console.log(myObj.value) // Outputs: "foo"
myObj.value = 'bar'
console.log(myObj.y) // Outputs: "bar"
```

But I see the next syntax is allowed in a plain JavaScript too:

```js
const myObj = {
  get() { return 'foo' },
  set(val) { this.y = val }
}
```

But I don't understand how to access those functions, and which cases they are used for?

Comment: Those are not getters and setters. those are just properties of the object that have a function as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people may be confused about this, but the `get` and `set` methods in the example you provided are only regular object methods (properties), they are not **getter** and **setter** properties.

```js
const myObj = {
  get() { return 'foo' },
  set(val) { this.y = val }
}
console.log(myObj.get());  // Outputs: "foo"
myObj.set("bar");
console.log(myObj.y);  // Outputs: "bar"
```

You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) the valid object properties.

Comment: "*They don't have a specific name*" - they're called "methods". The syntax is called a "method definition" (in both object literals and class bodies), and they are not unnamed as the question suggests.

Comment: The allowed syntax for object literals is described e.g. here on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) . Maybe it's helpful to add that the above object is equivalent to `{get: function(){...}, set: function(val) {...}}`. And that additionally there is also the getter/setter Syntax described [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) . So `get propertyName(){...}` .

Answer (score -1):

They are JavaScript Accessors (Getters and Setters).
Getters and setters allow you to define Object Accessors (Computed Properties).

JavaScript Getter (The get Keyword)

`This example uses a lang property to get the value of the language property.`

```
// Create an object:
const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  language: "en",
  get lang() {
    return this.language;
  }
};

// Display data from the object using a getter:
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.lang;
```

JavaScript Setter (The set Keyword)
`This example uses a lang property to set the value of the language property.`

```
const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  language: "",
  set lang(lang) {
    this.language = lang;
  }
};

// Set an object property using a setter:
person.lang = "en";

// Display data from the object:
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.language;
```

The difference is how you access your value:

```
// Display data from the object using a function:
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName();
```

```
// Display data from the object using a getter:
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName;
```

More about JavaScript Accessors (Getters and Setters) [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp).

Comment: No, they are not! Check the question in detail: there is no `lang` after the `get`.

Comment: He had syntax errors, so I linked him to the w3schools page to understand it. I don't see these syntax errors in the example as a reason not to answer the question.

Comment: Try executing the snippet! There is no syntax error.

Comment: I meant syntax errors in relation to getters and setters. He talked about getters and setters, but his example doesn't include it. The way he does it, he can only do it once in this object, hence the syntax error statement.

Comment: I edited the question. The question assume we all know about regular *getter* and *setter*, and the question is about a "special" case of them.
No need to explain what it *getter* and *setter*.